# Filtering field on view - Lotus 8.5

Tags: lotus-notes, query

I have one view with field that I called "Date".

I can´t filter the results for one date...

please help me.

Comment: Hi welcome to SuperUser. Some more information about you've tried and what your question is would be helpful for someone to be able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your Notes database is full text indexed, then you can enter a formula like this into the full text search bar:

```
FIELD Date = 04/10/2013
```